# Adding multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert

I am asked to add 8 rows into a table.

```
insert into Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate ) 
values ('207', '101', '5', null), ('207', '102', '5', null),
       ('207', '103', '5', null), ('207', '104', '5', null),
       ('207', '105', '5', null), ('207', '106', '5', null),
       ('207', '107', '5', null), ('207', '108', '5', null)
```

This operation works good with one value added but when adding multiple gives the error

> *Query failed to execute: near ",": syntax error*

What is missing?

Comment: what's DB server app? mysql, mssql, postgre, oracle?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Well it's just easy exercise.I think it uses SQlite.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database

Comment: try putting the table name and the column names in ``

Comment: @scones: those dreaded backticks only work for MySQL (and should be avoided in the first place).

Answer (score 3):

**A late answer** 
If your are using SQLITE version [3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html) or above, then multiple rows insert is possible by this syntax,

**SIMPLEST WAY**

```
INSERT INTO Rating (rID, mID, stars, ratingDate) VALUES ('207', '102', '5', null) , ('207', '102', '5', null) , ('207', '102', '5', null)
```

The above clause posted in question do work if the new SQLITE version is used.

**SELECT CLAUSE**

```
insert into Rating 
        SELECT '207' AS rID, '101' AS mID, '5' AS stars, null AS ratingDate   
  UNION SELECT '207', '102', '5', null
  UNION SELECT '207', '103', '5', null
  UNION SELECT '207', '104', '5', null
  UNION SELECT '207', '105', '5', null
  UNION SELECT '207', '106', '5', null            
  UNION SELECT '207', '107', '5', null
  UNION SELECT '207', '108', '5', null
```

or SQL is

```
insert into Rating (rID, mID, stars, ratingDate)
        SELECT '207', '101', '5', null 
  UNION SELECT '207', '102', '5', null
  UNION SELECT '207', '103', '5', null
  UNION SELECT '207', '104', '5', null
  UNION SELECT '207', '105', '5', null
  UNION SELECT '207', '106', '5', null            
  UNION SELECT '207', '107', '5', null
  UNION SELECT '207', '108', '5', null
```

**REMEMBER** I you do not want to check for duplicate in above set of inserted values then use `UNION ALL` in place of `UNION` as it will be little faster.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your RDBMS don't support such construction.

```
insert into Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate ) 
values ('207', '101', '5', null);
insert into Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate ) 
values ('207', '102', '5', null);
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

I sugest:

```
insert into Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate ) values ('207', '101', '5', null);
insert into Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate ) values ('207', '102', '5', null);
...
insert into Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate ) values ('207', '108', '5', null);
```

Comment: No,that doesn't work either.It says you can execute one statement at one time.

Answer (score 0):

i created table in sql lite . table creation script is as follows

```
 create table Rating (rID varchar(10),mID varchar(10),stars varchar(10),ratingDate date);
```

And i used following query to insert into above table and its working fine for me.

```
insert into Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate ) 
values ('207', '101', '5', null), ('207', '102', '5', null),
       ('207', '103', '5', null), ('207', '104', '5', null),
       ('207', '105', '5', null), ('207', '106', '5', null),
       ('207', '107', '5', null), ('207', '108', '5', null);
```

Comment: Let me give you more details.These are the tables I have : http://class2go.stanford.edu/db/Winter2013/pages/moviedata I am asked to "Insert 5-star ratings by James Cameron for all movies in the database. Leave the review date as NULL." Hope that helps :)

Comment: @JohnRock - i tried to open that url but got message "You must be logged-in to view the content you chose."

Comment: @JohnRock - if you give remote access,i think i can solve this

Comment: @JohnRock - goto following url, you can see screenshot of what i've done http://www74.zippyshare.com/v/92634544/file.html

Comment: If you create the table it works but it is already there.So it doesn't work.My understanding is I have to write a query that inserts these values not inserting them one by one.

Comment: @JohnRock - run following query and please tell me the result ".schema Rating"        (without quotes)

Comment: Fails to execute.I'm going nuts :S

Comment: @JohnRock - may be you forgot that dot(.) before schema . Above query will show you create query of Rating table

Comment: No I didn't.Can you join Class2Go and see it?It's Stanford's course.Name is Int to Databases.

Comment: How do I send you pm or something :)

Comment: @ i cant understand what you said

Comment: Is there a way to send you a message,privately?

Comment: Man I'm sorry.Skype is not working :( But good news is I solved the question.Here it is :  insert into Rating (rID, mID, stars, ratingDate)
select '207' as rID, '101' as mID, '5' as stars, null as ratingDate
union select '207', '102', '5', null
union select '207', '103', '5', null..... I'll add you as soon as it works :)

Comment: @JohnRock - Good. By the way the reason for skype not working may be the antivirus may be blocking skype. Try to disable antivirus and login in skype. Anyway Have a nice day .. Take care . bye